# why the text of label didn't show the result initialized in custom class?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

There is the complete process：

1. Create a project, choose Base class: **QWidget**, including **.h .cpp .ui**
2. [**Add New...**] -> create a [ **C++ class**] -> choose base class: [**QWidget**], but named **myLabel**.
3. Open **mylabel.h**, change **QWidget** of including file and parent class to **QLabel**
   **mylabel.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MYLABEL_H
#define MYLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>

class myLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

};

#endif // MYLABEL_H
```

4. Open **mylabel.cpp**, change the parent class into QLabel too, and set text content
   **mylabel.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mylabel.h"

myLabel::myLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel{parent}
{
    this->setText("test");
}
```

**widget.h**

```cpp
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```cpp
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

5. Now i got a custom class, and create a label in the **widget.ui**
   add a **widget**, put the **label** in, choose widget and label, **ctrl+L**
   [just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z05UJ.png)
6. Promote label to myLabel.
   [label was promoted to myLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5S1X.png)
7. Run.
   [running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEgD8.png)
   This isn't what i expect. 
   So, why the text of label didn't change? or maybe something ignored? plz, even a keyword that can help me searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code of `setupUi` method.

When you use QT Designer to create your widget, each widget has some properties (like geometry, object name, initial text for label etc) which have to be initialized. This is done in `setupUi`. The code corresponding your case may look like:

```
    void setupUi() {
      label = new myLabel(widgetParent); // setText with test
      label->setObjectName(...
      label->setGeometry(...
      label->setAlignment(...
      label->setText(TEXT_FROM_DESIGNER); // <--- 
    }
```

The text `test` set by constructor of `myLabel` widget is overwritten by calling `setText` in `setupUi` method with text choosen in Designer.

If you want to change some properties of created widgets it should be done after `setupUi`:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // change label's text
}
```

Comment: Yes, i just tried `qDebug( )`, the text i setted in class myLabel was outputed first, then the qDebug() after setupUi( ) was outputed. Thanks!